# How can I localize this Remarketing tag ?

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome-devtools, google-ads-api

I have the following website : `[http://besthealthlife.com/bg/softskin.html][1]`. Using Tag Assistant I can detect a Remarketing Tag installed somewhere in the website. However when looking in the source code I can't find anything that indicate me where/how this remarketing tag is being executed.

Using the tag conversion ID I have these informations from the Network Tab in the console dev tool :

[image]

However I'm know sure about what I should understand from this...

Any help ?

Comment: Screenshot with requests, which you attached, they coming from youtube video. You don't have Remarketing Tag installed on your website

Comment: @VictorLeontyev thanks. What do you mean exactly ? Is it because of a youtube video with a remarketing tag included ?

Comment: Yes, you right. That is exactly what i mean.

Comment: and what exactly make you say that's coming from Youtube ? I was thinking about that but not sure how I can justify it...

Comment: ok, let me prepare it as answer, because it will be better to include some screenshots to help you understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your question, you mention this HTTP requests:
[image]
All of this request are coming from embedded youtube video.

You can easily understand it, if you will click to "Group by frame" checkbox. It will show you that all of this requests are comming from `www.youtube.com` frame
[image]

That means, that you don't have Remarketing Tag installed on your website